# Searching for a default "check mark" icon

Tags: wpf, icons

I am currently searching for an icon that shows a green check mark, such as this:
[image]

Basically what I want to do is the following: My C# WPF application contains a ListView with some entries and each of the entry gets validated. Depending on the outcome of the validation, such a green check mark or a red cross should be displayed.

I found a very nice red cross in the class SystemIcons. It is called SystemIcons.Error. The SystemIcons class also provides other icons like "Exclamation", "hand", "Shield", "Question" and various other icons, however there is no such a check mark thing.

Does anyone know whether such a check mark icon exists in some default library? I googled but I could not find anything alike. In case there is no such Icon, I would have to take some image from the web (like I posted here), but that would be the last option since my application should look consistent and I'm pretty sure Microsoft uses lots of those green things in many places of Windows. So there must be some icon I could use, right?

Best wishes,
Christian

Comment: Just remember that "taking some image from the web" might violate somebody's copyright (depending on the "Schöpfungshöhe" of the image).

Comment: Of course, that's why I would rather want to use some system icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using one of the full versions of Visual Studio, you could always check out the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) that comes with Visual Studio.

I'm double checking now to make sure it contains something like what you're looking for.

Comment: That library is great, it contains a whole bunch of check marks! :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Hm I realise that there is again some vagueness about licensing here. Microsoft does not explicitly say anything about the license of these images.

Comment: @Christian - From the page I linked to, "The image library includes three main categories of images: animations, bitmaps, and icons. A readme file, *readme.htm, is included for each major area. These readme files include information about how to use these images appropriately in your applications."

Comment: This readme file says: "Use Restrictions
These common elements are to be used in the development and illustration of new custom imagery.  As part of a visual language, these images (or any part of the images) must be used in a manner consistent with the name of the file, which is self-descriptive of the annotation that the imagery represents."

This sounds very vague and unclear.

Comment: @Christian - Not to mention that the Image Library is only found with certain versions of Visual Studio. I'm guessing the license for Visual Studio gives you the license to use the images in the image library when developing.

Comment: @Justin Niessner - I hope so, but for now I will use these images. It seems as if it is not a problem.

Comment: Is there a VS2017 version of the library?

Comment: @Sheen - I'm not sure which version this is, but you could download and check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/the-visual-studio-image-library

Answer (score 2):

What size icon images do you need?

If 16x16 will do then I'd recommend the [silk icon set at famfamfam.com](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/). This set is nice and consistent, and contains a green check mark.

[image: a green check mark]

Comment: Yes I think 16x16 will do. The icons look good, but it would mean that I need to take all of them for the application. Thanks a lot, I think if windows does not sponsor a nice icon I will definitely go for that one!